# Limit on branch in Azure Deployment with GitHub

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

We have a github account which has a repository with more than 30 branches. We are using the Azure new portal in order to define a deployment slot. In the list of branches we only get 30 branches.

1. Is having so many branches frowned upon? (I guess i know the answer already)
2. How can we specify the name explicitly?
3. Should i start deleting branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you create a deployment, in the ftp you get a folder:

`/site/deployments`

In this folder there is a `Settings.xml` file.

I my case it looks as simple as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <deployment>
    <add key="branch" value="stage_deployment" />
  </deployment>
</settings>
```

So, one could just select one (valid) branch from the ones available, and then go and change the setting in the file. It really sounds as a workaround, but seems to be valid and no external tools needed other than an ftp client (which i guess you would already have).

Answer (score 1):

It's more a workaround than a solution to your problem, but you can configure deployment using a JSON Azure Resource Manager template.

You can see an example here : https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs/blob/master/azuredeploy.json

```
"repoURL": { 
    "type": "string", 
    "defaultValue": "https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs.git", 
     "metadata": { 
         "description": "The URL for the GitHub repository that contains the project to deploy." 
     } 
 }, 
 "branch": { 
     "type": "string", 
     "defaultValue": "master", 
     "metadata": {  
         "description": "The branch of the GitHub repository to use." 
     } 
 }
```

If you are not familiar with Azure Resource Manager, you can read this article : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/

Hope this helps,

Julien

Comment: This is really something i hoped it existed, but i did nit know where to look for. Please give me a while before i am able to test this.

Comment: I am reviewing this solution and really looks promising. I would like to ask though as i am not familiar with the REST API. I would like to do this task through the portal. I am on the template deployment view, but i really do not know what parameters i would need to put there. I guess what you have in code is just a part of what is needed (i know i need to also modify the values...).

Comment: If you want to explore your subscription in a "json-way" you can go on http://resource.azure.com, maybe it will help you. There is also some UI tools in Visual Studio with the last Azure SDK that may help with the JSON templates.

Comment: thanks, i will check this out. It also occured to me last night while sleeping.... that i may need to create an azuredeploy.json file and add it in my root and it will know what to do? Or maybe it was a very good dream to be true...